# How can I place a video and image inline, each half the width of the parent?

Tags: html, css

I would like to place a video and image next to each other, both being 50% of the parent. Below is the code I have tried. To me it looks like each wrapping div should be inline, 50%; with the child element filling the width.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div class="video-container">
    <video poster="Resources/css/img/ioposter.png" controls="true" muted loop>
        <source src="/Resources/img/vid.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
   </div>
   <div style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">
     <img style="width:100%;" src="Resources/myimg.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 0px;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   width:50%;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a quick jsFiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/L5euvkzm/2/

```
.wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

All I did was add a class to the outer div and then apply font-size: 0; The reason this happens like so is because there is white space added between the two containers. there are other approaches for this fix, but this the way I prefer for making elements stack nicely next to one another.

Comment: Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can accomplish it with Flexbox:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video poster="Resources/css/img/ioposter.png" controls="true" muted loop>
        <source src="/Resources/img/vid.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's how you can accomplish it with traditional floats:

```css
#wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video poster="Resources/css/img/ioposter.png" controls="true" muted loop>
        <source src="/Resources/img/vid.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```